# Oh my zsh / Iterm2 auto suggestion color is broken?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, zsh, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

see screenshot below.

Added my .zshrc file also below.

[image]

```
export NVM_DIR="$HOME/.nvm"
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/nvm.sh" # This loads nvm
[ -s "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion" ] && \. "$NVM_DIR/bash_completion"  # This loads nvm bash_completion


export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"


ZSH_THEME="eastwood"


plugins=(git zsh-syntax-highlighting zsh-autosuggestions sudo web-search copypath copyfile copybuffer dirhistory history jsontools macos ruby rails)

source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh


eval "$(/opt/homebrew/bin/brew shellenv)"
export PATH="$HOME/.rbenv/bin:$PATH"
eval "$(rbenv init -)"


export PATH="/Applications/Sublime Text.app/Contents/SharedSupport/bin:$PATH"
export PATH=/opt/homebrew/bin:$PATH
```

Comment: The screenshot looks fine. What's the problem? Aside from this, there is no `zsh` involved in the code you show in your screenshot, hence this is not related to either zsh or oh-my-zsh.

Comment: _"color is broken"_ – how is the color supposed to look?

Comment: @Stefan the contrast is too low. It should be like black background on white text. I can't read it.

Comment: It changes in my console exactly as described, also.  I hate it.  I don't remember suggestions popping up previously...now, when I start typing any model name, all my models pop up in the list.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## **Fixed by changing the color of LIGHT CYAN in iTerm2.**

And using theme "Dark Tango"

*See screenshots.*

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

It is a feature of irb and it is enabled as of Ruby 3.1

The new IRB console has an autocomplete function where a list with suggestions appears, and in addition, the documentation (if exists) of the selected option will appear.

You can disable it by adding code below to the `~/.irbrc` file

```rb
IRB.conf[:USE_AUTOCOMPLETE] = false
```

Or if you just want to turn off colors:

```rb
IRB.conf[:USE_COLORIZE] = false
```

Or if you want to see or/and to change other settings of your IRB enviroment type `IRB.conf` in your `irb` console.

Comment: Thanks, I researched and found you can't change the colors as this is from the new irb console. I'm running "rails console". I added IRB.conf[:USE_COLORIZE] = false
IRB.conf[:NO_COLOR] = true to ~/.irbrc and /app_dir/.irbrc but still it's using the light blue color. Is there some rails console configuration that's overriding it?

Comment: `IRB.conf[:USE_COLORIZE] = false` this setting turns off colors in console, not color background for autosuggetion

Comment: Any idea how to fix it the background for auto suggestion? I haven’t got it fixed yet.

Comment: Looks like this is an open issue in irb without a fix just yet... There was a change in ruby/reline added to help... Soon we'll be able to set:

```
IRB.conf[:DIALOG_DEFAULT_BG_COLOR] = 40
IRB.conf[:DIALOG_POINTER_BG_COLOR] = 47
IRB.conf[:DIALOG_DEFAULT_FG_COLOR] = 31
IRB.conf[:DIALOG_POINTER_FG_COLOR] = 30
```

But I think we're waiting on a commit in `irb` now. See:

https://github.com/ruby/irb/pull/337